# Logging Chrooted Users SFTP Activity

Tags: linux, centos, logs, chroot, sftp

So I'm having the issue where I can't seem to log users SFTP activity. I can see when a new session was created by a specific user, but can't see where they've been or what they may have dropped within the directory.

My SFTP users are all chrooted in the same place (/data/SFTP/) - each one does not have a specific folder.

My directory looks like this:

`/data/SFTP/SFTPHome`

Every SFTP user has access to the /SFTPHome directory, but not its parent directories.

---

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

`Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f AUTH -l VERBOSE`

```
Match Group SFTPUsers
        PasswordAuthentication no
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ChrootDirectory /data/SFTP/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -f AUTH -l VERBOSE
```

---

/etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
# Logs all SFTP activity
auth.*                                                  /var/log/sftp.log
```

With this in place, the only information that fills the /var/log/sftp.log is

```
Feb 13 16:05:59 Host_SFTP systemd-logind: New session 30 of user JOHNSON.
Feb 13 16:06:30 Host_SFTP systemd-logind: Removed session 30.
Feb 13 16:09:17 Host_SFTP sshd[7126]: rexec line 63: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Feb 13 16:09:32 Host_SFTP systemd-logind: New session 31 of user JOHNSON.
Feb 13 16:09:32 Host_SFTP systemd-logind: Removed session 31.
Feb 13 16:14:17 Host_SFTP sshd[7154]: rexec line 63: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Feb 13 16:14:24 Host_SFTP sshd[7156]: rexec line 63: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Feb 13 16:14:32 Host_SFTP systemd-logind: New session 32 of user JOHNSON.
Feb 13 16:14:57 Host_SFTP systemd-logind: Removed session 32.
```

How can I set this up so I can monitor where and what files are being placed within the SFTP directory?

Comment: Try log level DEBUG3 instead of VERBOSE. If you still aren't getting anything, there may be a problem logging from inside the chroot jail.

Comment: Just tried that - no changes. I have a feeling that the issue has to do with its logging inside the chroot jail, but at that point I'm  a bit lost and not sure what I should do..